# Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.validatorListener is not a function

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am implementing form validation inside my material-ui TextField using the library `react-form-validator-core` as follows:

It just looks like the documentation example, where I am extending the ValidatorComponent. This allows accessing different props and `isValid` from the parent state.

#### TextInput component

```
class TextInput extends ValidatorComponent {
  /**
   * render the component
   * @returns {object} JSX
   */
  render() {
    const {
      variant,
      id,
      label,
      autoFocus,
      multiline,
      rows,
      error,
      errorMessages,
      validators,
      requiredError,
      helperText,
      withRequiredValidator,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    const { isValid } = this.state;

    return (
      <TextField
        {...rest}
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
        variant={variant}
        id={id}
        name={id}
        label={label}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        multiline={multiline}
        rows={rows}
        error={!isValid || error}
        helperText={(!isValid && this.getErrorMessage()) || helperText}
      />
    );
  }
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  helperText: PropTypes.string,
  variant: PropTypes.string,
  autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
  multiline: PropTypes.bool,
  rows: PropTypes.string,
};

TextInput.defaultProps = {
  error: false,
  helperText: undefined,
  variant: 'outlined',
  autoFocus: false,
  multiline: false,
  rows: '8',
};

export default TextInput;
```

#### My Form

I am using the Vali

```
<ValidatorForm
 className={classes.form}
  autoComplete="off"
  noValidate
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
>
  <TextInput
    id="email"
    label="Email"
    autoFocus={false}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    value={email}
    validators={['required', 'isEmail']}
    errorMessages={['this field is required', 'email is not valid']}
  />
  <Box marginTop={2}>
    <Button variant="contained" type="submit" className="button" fullWidth>
      send message
    </Button>
  </Box>
</ValidatorForm>
```

#### Problem

I don't understand why every time I enter a value on the TextField, I am getting this error. I would like to know the effective way of using this library alongside material-ui.

Here is the way the two functions are implemented

#### onChange

```
onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

#### handleSubmit

```
  handleSubmit() {
    const { email } = this.state;
    console.log(email);
  }
```

Comment: Please show how handleSubmit and handleChange are defined and bound.

Comment: I am just going throw this out here as an FYI. React Team strongly discourages using [inheritance over composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Comment: Hey @AlexanderStaroselsky  I updated my question with the `handleSubmit` and `handleChange` methods

Comment: Hey @Gasim, you mean I don't have to inherit the `ValidatorComponent` as I did?

Comment: @coolbeatz71 this library implemented their functionality through inheritance; so, you don't really have any other choice than to use the library's API. If you still have the chance, migrate to a library that is more aligned with React's principles.

Comment: Btw, the problem you have is in `defaultProps`. You are extending `ValidatorComponent` that has a default prop [`validatorListener: () => {}`](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-form-validator-core/blob/master/src/ValidatorComponent.jsx#L134); then overriding the default props in `TextInput`. Just add this prop to `TextInput`'s default props or do something like `TextInput.defaultProps = { ...ValidatorComponent.defaultProps, YOUR_PROPS_HERE }`. **This is one of the many reasons why React prefers composition over inheritance.**

Comment: Okay @Gasim, Let me give it a try

Comment: Wow, @Gasim your solution worked.